# Does anyone know how to implement Auth0 hosted login page?

Tags: authentication, auth0

I am working on a SPA (Angular 1.5.x with Auth0) and saw that I could customize the widget login page. Auth0 provided a generated custom login's URL that includes the Client ID, but no visible instructions on how to integrate it into my project.

If anyone has, can you provide instructions as to how you integrated the Auth0 Hosted Login Page?

Comment: Your question is far too broad and vague, unless you would find either *Yes, someone has used this feature* or *No, no one has ever used this feature* acceptable answers. If neither of them will suit your needs, you need to [edit] your question and make it much more specific. See [Real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 1):

You can show this login page by redirecting to the [/authorize endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#!#get--authorize_social) and not specifying a `connection` parameter. If a `connection` is specified, the user will directly by redirected to log in with that specific identity provider.

Comment: I am not quite clear on your instructions, but thank you for pointing me in a direction.

Comment: No problem. This is what the flow looks like for SPAs: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols#oauth2-implicit-flow

Comment: I finally heard back from Auth0 on this topic. The login page in your Auth0 account can be customized, but it is more of a demo. If you want that simple design in your app, you have to make the same changes local to your app. In other words, you cannot access the Hosted Login Page in your app.
@Rodrigo López Dato
I already have the generic lock widget configured in my application. I think you misunderstood what I was asking for.

Comment: this answer seems to be right, not the comment about it being a "demo"